# Why filtering is not working on my data in kendo grid

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid

I'm trying to implement server-side filtering in kendo grid.

I have post request "/api/Account/Filter" which returns the filter data,
I also checked that from fiddler which is meant its work but I don't know why after filter calls the kendo grid updated with all data!

Here is my code:

```
        $scope.DS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: "json",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/api/Employees",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken") }
                },
                update: {
                    url: "/api/Employees/PUT",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "PUT",
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken") }
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "/api/Employees/DELETE",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "DELETE",
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken") } },
                create: {
                    url: "/api/Employees/POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: "POST",
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken") }  },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read") {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(options.models));
                        return JSON.stringify(options.models);
                    }}},
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 5,
            serverFiltering: true,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                   data: 'Data',
                   total: 'Total',
                  //  errors: 'Errors',
                    fields: {
             Id: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "number" },
           Email: { editable: true, type: "string" },
            UserName: {editable: true,type: "string"},
   FirstName: { editable: true, type: "string" },
     LastName: { editable: true, type: "string"},
   Age: { editable: true,  validation: { required: true } },
   Phone: { editable: true, validation: { required: true } },
     Department: { editable: true,type: "string"}
     } }
            },
        });

        $scope.mainGridOptions = {
            dataSource: $scope.DS,
            dataBound: function () {
  var data = this.dataSource.view();
            },
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                { field: "Email", title: "Email", width: "100px" },
                { field: "UserName", title: "User Name", width: "100px"},
               { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width:"100px"},
             { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: "100px" },
                { field: "Phone", title: "Phone", width: "100px" },
                { field: "Age", title: "Age", width: "100px" },
             { field: "Department", title: "Department", width: "100px"},
                {
                    command: [{
                        name: "edit",
                        text: {
                            edit: "Edit",
                            update: "Save",
                            cancel: "Cancel"
                        }
                    }, "destroy"], title: "Actions", width: "150px"
                }
            ],
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                input: true,
                numeric: false,
                pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100, 500, 1000]
            },
            sortable: true,
            resizable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            editable: { mode: "inline" },
            filter: function (data) {
                console.log((data));
                console.log((data.filter));
                const requestOptions = {
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken") }
                };
                $http.post("/api/Account/Filter", data, requestOptions).then(function (d) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(d.data.Data));
                    // $scope.DS.read = d.data.Data;
                    debugger;
                    $scope.mainGridOptions.dataSource.query(d.data.Data);

                }, function () {
                alert("Failed.Please try again.")
                    });
            },

            noRecords: { template: "No results available."}

        };
```

The following code is in controller to get all data:

```
  public List<RegisterBindingModel> GET()
        {
            var user = db.Users.Select(x => new RegisterBindingModel()
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Email = x.Email,
                    UserName = x.UserName,
                    FirstName = x.FirstName,
                    LastName = x.LastName,
                    Age = x.Age,
                    Phone = x.Phone,
                    Department = x.Department
                });
                return user.ToList();
```

This is for filter in server side:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET","POST")]
    public IHttpActionResult Filter(Models.DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        request.Skip = 0;
        request.Take = 5;
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Filter.Field = request.Filter.Filters.FirstOrDefault().Field;
            request.Filter.Operator = request.Filter.Filters.FirstOrDefault().Operator;
            request.Filter.Value = request.Filter.Filters.FirstOrDefault().Value;
            var o = request;
        }
        var employees = db.Users.OrderBy(ii => ii.Id).Select(x => new RegisterBindingModel()
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Email = x.Email,
            UserName = x.UserName,
            FirstName = x.FirstName,
            LastName = x.LastName,
            Age = x.Age,
            Phone = x.Phone,
            Department = x.Department
        });
        var i = employees.ToDataSourceResult(request.Take, request.Skip, request.Sort, request.Filter);
        var data = i.Data; // This is contain filtered data
        request.Take = i.Total;
        var d = Json(data);
        return Json(new { Data = data, Total = request.Take });
        //return data.Cast <RegisterBindingModel>().ToList();
    }
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check your browser's network and error console? Are there any errors? If not, are the correct data sent to the controller? Did you debug your controller, do you get the expected data?

Comment: Yes, but after come back from controller with filter data, the parameterMap run again with read operation and go back to read all data. I updated the question with read method in controller.